# Replacing matrix rows for a vector without using a loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Is it possible to replace some rows of a matrix for specific vectors (in my case, random vectors) without using a loop in MATLAB?

Given:

```
A = [1 2 3; 
     4 5 6; 
     7 8 9; 
     10 11 12]
```

I want to replace `A([2 3],:)` with, for instance, `v = rand(1,3)` but I really want that each chosen row (in this case 2 and 3) of `A` is randomly generated.

The problem with this is that I want to generalize it to do it for every given matrix `A` without using a loop in MATLAB. Is it possible?

Thank you.
Rui Semeano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
A([2 3],:) = rand(2,size(A,2));
```

You get the number of columns in `A` by `size(A,2)`, and then create a random matrix with the needed size and just assign it to the `A`.

If you want also to choose the rows randomly, then for `N` rows you can write:

```
N = 2;
randRows = randperm(size(A,1),N);
A(randRows,:) = rand(N,size(A,2))
```

P.S - if you want to randomize integers, use [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html).

Comment: hank you very much for your answers! And I am so sorry that I wasn't more specific and made you waste time, but what I actually wanted was to know was if there was a way to change some rows of a matrix to a generated vector without using a loop (or repmat). I am truly sorry for the misunderstood.

Comment: @RuiSemeano there is no loop in this answer and this is exactly what it does. The first version for a predefined rows (2 and 3) and the second for random N rows. What are you missing?

Comment: The problem is that I really should have been more specific. I don't want to use a "random generator" built in funcion. I want to use my "random generator" which outputs only one vector, not a matrix. So I want every selected row of A to be replaced by a random generated vector without using a loop or repmat. But anyway I think the better solution is to give my random generator the ability to output a matrix instead of just a vector. Thank you for your patience

Comment: @RuiSemeano So in your example, rows 2 and 3 in `A` will be replaced by the same random vector, or you generate a different vector for each row? And also, do you randomize the rows to change (e.g. 2 and 3) or you give them as input? And why then you accepted the other answer?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to stackoverflow I thought it meant like a check mark or something... none of the answers solved my problem but it was my fault so I validated for the effort, but I didn't noticed I could only validate one... Rows 2 and 3 should be replaced each by a call to my random function so they should be replaced by a different vector each (but can be equal by chance). No, I simply have one matrix, then I choose (randomly) some rows of that matrix and I want to replace each row by a call to my function which output is a random vector (with compatible dimension, of course.

Comment: Well, the best option will be that your function that generates the vectors will return a matrix n-by-m where n is the number of rows to be replaced and m is the number of columns in `A` (the original matrix). Then you can use it just like I use `rand` in this answer. If this is not possible, and you want each row to be replaced by a different vector, then you need a loop, but that is not so bad. In the recent versions of MATLAB a simple `for` loop is very fast.

Comment: Ooh that's good news!! I have been crazy worried about "efficiency" of my code since I am a beginner and wanted to make things as right as possible (it's for a work in a master thesis). And because of that I have been obsessed with "vectorizing" because most of the people I've talked to demonises loops in MATLAB... and then I absorbed this prejudice against loops... Anyway thank you very much for your help!! It was really enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

It sound like you want to generate the `[2,3]` randomly? I wasn't sure so I just named everything verbosely and made everything random.

```
MinimumInteger = 1;
MaximumInteger = 12;
NumberOfRows = 4;
NumberOfColums = 3;

A = randi([MinimumInteger, MaximumInteger], NumberOfRows, NumberOfColums);

NumberOfRowsToChange = randi([0, NumberOfRows]);

RowsToChange = randperm(NumberOfRows, NumberOfRowsToChange);

A(RowsToChange, :) = randi([MinimumInteger, MaximumInteger], NumberOfRowsToChange, NumberOfColums);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! And I am so sorry that I wasn't more specific and made you waste time, but what I actually wanted was to know was if there was a way to change some rows of a matrix to a generated vector without using a loop (or repmat). I am truly sorry for the misunderstood.